# Why do I get a segmentation fault when looping through this vector?

Tags: c++, vector, segmentation-fault, c++14

When I run this code I get a segmentation fault. I'm using C++ 14 with Clion. It looks like it crashes on the 6th or 7th loop. It seems like it is coming from where I am erasing elements from the vector. If there is a better way to iterate through vectors please let me know, I'm still trying to learn to code in C++.

```
#include <vector>
#include <synchapi.h>

class someClass{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    int health = 0;
    someClass(int a, int b){
        x = a;
        y = b;
    }
};

std::vector<someClass> classList;

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) {
        someClass newclass(i, i*3);
        classList.push_back(newclass);
    }

    while(true) {
        int iter = 0;
        if(!classList.empty()) {
            for (auto &e: classList) {

                if (e.health == 0) {
                    classList.erase(classList.begin() + iter); 
                    if(iter != 0){
                        iter--;
                    }
                }
                iter++;
            }
        }
        Sleep(50);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are erasing inside a range based loop. There are ways to do that, but you must maintain either the index or iterators yourself.

Comment: Use the [erase-remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom) instead.

Comment: Use [std::remove_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) instead of your own loop, don't forget to call erase after that as shown in the example too.

Comment: Doesn't help with C++14, but for those using C++20 we now also have [std::erase_if](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) that does the whole job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you modify a collection *while* iterating over it, bad things tend to happen.

If you need to modify the original collection, use the [remove-erase idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom).

```
std::erase(
  std::remove_if(
    classList.begin(), classList.end(),
    [](auto &x){ return x.health == 0; }
  ),
  classList.end()
);
```

If you don't need to modify the original collection, you might copy the elements you don't want to remove to a new collection.

```
std::vector<someClass> classList2;

std::copy_if(
  classList.begin(), classList.end(),
  std::back_inserter(classList2),
  [](auto &x){ return x.health != 0; }
);
```

*As a style note, using "list" in the name of a variable that is a vector is a bit misleading. As variable names should denote meaning of the data rather than type, it would be best to avoid this type of naming altogether.*

Comment: About the style note: Variable names should convey the *meaning* of the values, not the *types*. Having a variable *classList* of type *vector* is totally fine.

Comment: I have clarified that note.